# Definitive join MP3's in ffmpeg or avconv - whats the magic line of code?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, avconv

I have some MP3's they need to be concatenated in to a single MP3.

What is the command line I need for FFMPEG or AVCONV to do this?

I don't know or care about the quality/bit-rate etc of the inputs, I have what I have and they are random.

I have hunted far and wide and found loads of people who like to talk about pages of useless detail that makes absolutely no difference to me...

So...

I have been using:

ffmpeg -i "concat:file1.mp3|file2.mp3" -b:a:320000 -acodec file3.mp3

The output sounds fine, but the output file often shows the duration and bitrate wrong on the output... what is the magic line of code I seek?

I am in no hurry - and can run the files through a dozen other processes if needed, and if quality goes down I *really* *really* don't care - I just want a fully functional MP3 at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ffmpeg -i file1.mp3 -i file2.mp3 \
-filter_complex "concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a]"
-map [a] -b:a:320k -write_xing 0 file3.mp3
```